# MobileFirst HTTP Adapter: delete/update back-end cookie value

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using `WL.Server.invokeHttp(options)` several times in my adapter. I need to have different values for a given cookie in different calls.

If I call

```
WL.Server.invokeHttp({cookies: { 
                        mycookie: 'firstValue'
                        }
                      ...
```

the back-end gets this header `"cookie": "mycookie=firstValue"`, as expected.

If I later want to make another call with a different cookie value,

```
WL.Server.invokeHttp({cookies: { 
                        mycookie: 'secondValue'
                        }
                      ...
```

the back-end gets this header `"cookie": "mycookie=firtsValue; mycookie=secondValue"`.

Is there some way that will let me forget a previous value of the cookie?

**Update 2015/02/27**

Using the `headers` option instead of the `cookies` option, as suggested by @YoelNunez, does not solve it.

1. My first request gets a `"set-cookie": "name=value1; Path=/"` response header
2. My second request sets `headers: {cookie: 'name=value2'}`
3. The second requests gets to the server with the following header `"cookie": "name=value2, name=value1"`

Answer (score 0):

Change you `invokeHttp` to the following

```
WL.Server.invokeHttp({
    headers: {
        cookie: "mycookie="+myCookieValue
    }
    ...
});
```

Where `myCookieValue` is your variable

Comment: Thanks, Yoel. Unfortunately, it does not work. See my updated question

Comment: @Xv. what is your MobileFirst full version? I'm using 6.3.0.00-20150130-1638 and when I send the same cookie more than once with a different value then it updates the value in the cookie header.

Comment: mine looks newer: 6.3.0.00.20150204-0559

Comment: @Xv. does your backend get the right value for the updated cookie or does it pick the first one and doesn't update on subsequent calls?

Comment: The real backend is outside my control. Thus, I need to send a cookie header that does not have any ambiguities. 

Since [I saw no way to inspect the traffic with the real back-end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738280/ibm-mobilefirst-inspecting-the-http-adapter-to-back-end-traffic), I created a small express.js back-end to inspect the received headers.

Comment: @Xv., not sure if that means you've found the solution to this question or not.

Comment: @IdanAdar, no WL.Server.invokeHttp is not doing properly cookie management: that's what my own small back-end allowed me to verify.

Comment: Okay. If you can reproduce this with a small test case app then please email me (find me on IBM's faces website) so that we'll open a defect.